# Asp.Net Core SignalR Can Not Connect From Android Studio Emulator Client - negotiation problem

Tags: reactjs, android-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I work on a project and want to invoke specific hub method from React and listen to it in Android app.

**My .net hub:**

```
public class StreamHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task StreamTester(string data)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("RecieveStream", data);
        }
    }
```

I invoke **StreamTester** method from React and it works fine (I tested `.on` response in React) and I want to listen **RecieveStream** in my Android app.

I am trying to connect to hub with .net SignalR client and it keeps returning DISCONNECTED state when I log it. [Negotiation with hub on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9k5n.png)

On picture we can see it actually tries to negotiate but when I log hubConnection state it returns me DISCONNECTED.[Hub connection state log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXRWo.png)

**This is my .java code:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createHubConnection();

        hubConnection.on("RecieveStream", (data) -> {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.streamData)).setText(data);
        }, String.class);

    }

    private void createHubConnection() {
        hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create("http://10.0.2.2:5000/streamHub").build();

        if (hubConnection.getConnectionState() == HubConnectionState.DISCONNECTED) {
            hubConnection.start();
        }
    }

    public void startStream(View v) {

        Log.d("connection", hubConnection.getConnectionState().toString());
    }
```

startStream is just event listener for button to check connection.

**My build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0-${System.env.VERSION_SHA}"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.25'
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, maybe my gradle is not correct?
I checked my firewall settings and all needed ports are opened.

Comment: It may be ALLOW DENY order of the server - or do you need to white list your app/IP

Comment: My React app normally connects to http://localhost:5000/streamHub ( in android I replaced localhost with 10.0.2.2 as many sources suggested) so I think that connection is possible but somehow it is not the case with app that I run on emulator in android studio.